# Use NewClassWizard in kentico admin

Tags: kentico

I want to create a custom page that allows me to track manually every data modification made by kentico in the database
I understood that I can implement it by code by using the NewClassWizard. But when done how I can use it in Kentico admin ? 
I try to load it from Page Type module but can find a way to specify my custom class
Is it the right way to use that? The documentation is not really clear on that
thanks for your help

Comment: Your question is a bit cryptic.  Can you provide more explanation of what exactly you're looking for?  I'm not sure it's possible to track every specific change Kentico makes to the database without using some database logging (which would be better served for this IMHO).

Comment: the main idea is to implement a ci/cd because we use kentico for a customer that have many sites (for each country)... so we need to track db changes

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a [global event handler](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/custom-development/handling-global-events) to track changes.  While Kentico will already do a lot of this tracking for you, you can specifically add whatever specific events you want as a global event.  This will handle any changes made on the customer-facing public website, inside the Kentico UI, and in any Kentico API calls.

In your custom global event handler, you can check for [different types of events](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events) based on the object and the CRUD activity.  For instance something like this:

```
using CMS;
using CMS.CustomTables;
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.DocumentEngine;

// Registers the custom module into the system
[assembly: RegisterModule(typeof(CustomInitializationModule))]

public class CustomInitializationModule : Module
{
    // Module class constructor, the system registers the module under the name "CustomInit"
    public CustomInitializationModule()
        : base("CustomInit")
    {
    }

    // Contains initialization code that is executed when the application starts
    protected override void OnInit()
    {
        base.OnInit();

        // Assigns custom handlers to events
        DocumentEvents.Insert.After += Document_Insert_After;
    }

    private void Document_Insert_After(object sender, DocumentEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.ClassName.ToLower() == "your.classname")
        {
            // create an event to log to a custom module table or a custom table so it's not logged directly in the Kentico Event log
            CustomTableItem item = new CustomTableItem("customtable.name");
            item.SetValue("ItemEventType", "Create document");
            item.SetValue("ItemEventCode", "Your event code");
            item.SetValue("ItemEventUserID", e.Node.DocumentModifiedByUserID);
            item.SetValue("ItemEventUrl", e.Node.NodeAliasPath);
            item.SetValue("ItemEventName", e.Node.DocumentName);
            item.Insert();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simple example of when a document is created. You don't have to check the page type's classname if you don't want to.  You can also include a global event handler for any "object" like a `cms_class` object, just use that definition in your code `<name>Info.TYPEINFO.Events.<eventtype>`.  This is not limited to any object, you can track transformation updates, page type field modifications, etc. You just need to know the object name/type and write code around it.